# List all files and folders which have a question mark (?) in their name

Tags: linux, find

I ran into an encoding problem when copying lots of files and folders from a Windows system to a Linux one and now I can see plenty of files with question mark in their name.

I'd like to know how many files/folders are impacted and so I tried

```
find . -type d -o -type f -name '*\?*'
```

and

```
find . -type d -o -type f -name '*?*'
```

with no luck.

It lists a lot of files/folders which have no question mark in their name... (please note that the search must be recursive)

Do you have a solution ?

(In addition, if you have a second command to count how many files are impacted, I'd be happy :) )

[edit] Thanks for your answers but the problem seems actually to be that those file and folders are excluded from the `find` command because of the encoding issue. First, it appears it is not the ? character but more something like �. And I try to perform the search on some other part of their name and they still don't appear (if I rename them, I get rid of the encoding issue, and they get visible again to `find`).
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9093719/6408940) helped me to list and count them.

Thanks

Comment: The first command works for me.

Comment: What kind of Linux are you using? I tested `find . -name '*\?*'` in Ubuntu 14 and worked fine for me.

Comment: You don't need the `-type d -o -type f` as `find` searches both for directories and files by default. You can pipe `wc -l` after `find` for a counter

Comment: You put a solution in the question. If it solves your problem, you should write it as an answer. If not, what is the actual question now?

Comment: The command in the linked answer, `find . | perl ...` still starts with `find`, yet you claim that the files and directories are invisible to `find`. I suggest you better describe your situation, possibly adding screenshots if you can't copy/paste a few sample filenames because of charset issues. Moreover, I would consider opening a new question since the ones you asked have already been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You have an encoding problem that should be resolved.

The `?` displayed by `ls` is a placeholder and doesn't mean the file is named `?`.

This is how to reproduce your problem, using [`iconv`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/iconv.1.en.html), on an usual utf8 configured Linux system:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test
$ cd /tmp/test
$ touch $(echo é | iconv -t windows-1252) # that's the eacute character
$ ls
?
$ ls|cat
�
```

The last line just means "invalid utf8 encoding is displayed" and probably can't be copy/pasted correctly without losing its information. `windows-1252` is just an example. It could have been many others (eg: `iso-8859-1`). The information is still there:

```
$ ls|iconv -f windows-1252
é
```

So once you figure out which encoding was used to write those files on Linux (try `iconv -l|egrep -i 'win|iso-8859'` for a possible candidate list), you could try some batch renaming. Be careful while an example might work, it might fail on an other file.

Example of renaming:

```
ENCODING="windows-1252" # once the right encoding was found
for file in *; do
    dest="$(printf '%s' "$file" | iconv -f "$ENCODING")"
    mv -i "$file" "$dest.new"
    mv -i "$dest.new" "$dest"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first command can be amended as follows:

```
find . -type d  -name '*\?*' -o -type f -name '*\?*'
```

This way, the filter applies to both files and directories (otherwise you would list all directories and only filter files).

---

Much simpler, as suggested by [Jimmy_A](https://superuser.com/users/726445/jimmy-a) in the comments, would be:

```
find . -name '*\?*'
```

Note that `find` searches by default in the current directory, so the `.` can be omitted as well:

```
find -name '*\?*'
```

---

As an alternative, you could grep the results:

```
find | grep ?
```

---

To count the relevant entities (solution suggested by [Jimmy_A](https://superuser.com/users/726445/jimmy-a)):

```
find | grep ? | wc -l
```

---

> command to count how many files are impacted

To count only files as you seem to be asking:

```
find -type f | grep ? | wc -l
```

---

Test run:

```
?aa
a?a
aa?
aaa
$ find | grep ?
./a?a
./?aa
./aa?
```

**Comment:**

I thought `grep` would need the `-F` option to treat `?` literally, but it appears it's not consideres a special character anyway, unless the `-E` switch is used.

> ```
>    -F, --fixed-strings
>           Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.
>
>    -E, --extended-regexp
>           Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).
> ```

---

**The question was updated:**

> List all files and folders which have a question mark (�) in their name

Not much changes: either `find -name '*�*'` or `find | grep �`

Test run:

```
�aa
a�a
aa�
aaa
$ find -name '*�*'
./a�a
./�aa
./aa�
```

---

**Another problem still:**

If you want to find files or directories that contain exotic characters, you could filter the results by specifying which characters you *expect*. Just add to the list any character you *don't* want to highlight:

```
find | grep -P '[^\w./-_*]'
```

This is especially useful when you *don't know* which is the problematic character. Pleae note this is a question that has been asked and answered already several times on the Stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

`find`'s `-o` means "*or*", so you might have an issue with precedance...

Which did you mean?

- `-type d` *or* (`-type f` *and* `-name '*\?*'`)

  - all directories
  - all files with `?` in their name
- (`-type d` *or* `-type f`) *and* `-name '*\?*'`

  - only directories and files with `?` in their name

You can use braces with `find`, so your command becomes:

```
find . \( -type d -o -type f \) -name '*\?*'
```

---

Example:

```
$ touch 'aaa' 'a?a'
$ mkdir 'bbb' 'b?b'
$ touch 'bbb/ccc' 'bbb/c?c'
```

```
$ find . -type d -o -type f -name '*\?*'
.
./bbb
./bbb/c?c
./b?b
./a?a
```

```
$ find . \( -type d -o -type f \) -name '*\?*'
./bbb/c?c
./b?b
./a?a
```

You can then pipe the output into `wc -l` to count the number of lines:

```
$ find . \( -type d -o -type f \) -name '*\?*' | wc -l
3
```

---

Others are suggesting that you remove the `-type d -o -type f`. This is a good option, unless you are trying to exclude other types (e.g: block device / character device / symlinks / pipes / sockets)